# Q: ui-grid's contentMenu with e.stopPropagation()

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I'm using the angular `ui-grid 3.0.7`  
I need to add the `e.stopPropagation()` in  directive,but it causes some    problems that the close button in ui-grid's contentMenu(on the right top) doesnt't work


here is the code

https://plnkr.co/edit/QNCEzKPAJz7inUdT6tYW?p=preview